# mySQL database: printing specific row or rows from a db table

Tags: php, mysql

please assist. i have a database with a couple of tables and rows and i want the php to print specific rows as and when i want it to. at the moment it renders all the content of the spesific table on my webpage. in future, i would like it to display the contents of a specific table if a cirtain user is logged in so im going to do that when i understand if statements and get over this hurdle 1st. my code is as follows:

```
 <?php
include 'connect-mysql.php';

echo "<br/>";

$query  = "SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, RAMSCODE  FROM customer";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "{$row['CUSTOMER_NAME']} <br>" .
         "RAMSCODE: {$row['RAMSCODE']} <br>" ;
} 

?>
```

Comment: How do you plan on identifying that specific user? How do you know who's logged in? a cookie? a session? what?

Answer (score 4):

To fetch specific rows from a table you have to include a WHERE clause in your SQL statement.

For example:

```
$query  = "SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, RAMSCODE  FROM customer WHERE customer_id = 2";
```

Match the `WHERE xxxxx` clause to any column in your table

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was fairly easy

Comment: if it solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the solution. it helps leflings!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifiy yor criteria as a where clause in the SQL

```
$query  = "SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, RAMSCODE  FROM customer where RAMSCODE = %1";
$result = mysql_query($query,mysql_real_escape_string($yourcode)) or die (mysql_error());
```

Also you really need to Read the Manuals!

Comment: Would someone care to explain why this (and @leflings) answers were down voted. Using a where clause in the select statement is as correct an answer as possible given the lack of detail in the question. I accept that the Read The Manuals comment may have come accross as a little flippant but its good advice.

Comment: Your answer seems good. Maybe someone thought that the string sanitization was not pertinent to the question. But I will vote you back up to zero.

Comment: @Buttle -- I know the string sensitization and placeholders make the answer more verbose -- but I am loath to post an answer that is open to the dreaded "sql injection" or "cross site scripting" attacks.

Comment: yes, I would probably include that stuff as well. I can only guess why someone would have voted it down, and that's the only thing I can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i've get what you want is to display only that row from customers table, which customer is logged in. you can use some thing like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['CUSTOMER_NAME'] == " //Customer Logged In (customer name from session)"){
         echo "{$row['CUSTOMER_NAME']} <br>" .
         "RAMSCODE: {$row['RAMSCODE']} <br>" ;
    }else{
         //do nothing or continue with printing all
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Filtering in the application does not scale!

Comment: "does not scale" is too vague a comment for a beginner. like, for instance, the poster, and me.

Comment: @toon81 The point I think is that you could have gotten the correct information from the database in the first place, making this while loop unnecessary. Why loop through a million rows in PHP when you could have just retrieved 1 row with the right MySQL query. I think that's what James was referring to.